# Signature verification for Repository openSUSE:update-sle failed

Tags: opensuse

This morning my opensuse leap 15.5 OS , don' t update and gives the following error:
"Signature verification for Repository openSUSE:update-sle failed ".
Did this happen to someone else?
there is a workaround?

Comment: You would be better looking at the Suse forums for such things.

Comment: It might be that the key is expired or has been invalidated for some reason or another; in any case you might be able to determine that yourself with `find /var/cache/zypp/raw/ -type f -name "*.key" | xargs -i -t gpg --list-packets {} | grep -P "(sig created|key expires)"` though I second the reccomendation for the SuSE forums, and this thread: https://forums.opensuse.org/t/where-does-zypper-install-the-repository-or-package-signing-keys/100773/2